# fmx delphi berlin how to change font color in rows of Tgrid

Tags: delphi, fonts, firemonkey, delphi-10.1-berlin, tgrid

NEED HELP..I am using delphi 10.1 berlin. There are some different with other previus version of Embarcadero Delphy  Code Gear. I need to change font color in rows of TGrid. Whith this next code i will change backgrond color but i need to change only Font Color :

```
  aRowColor.Color := arSTATUS_GRID_COLOR[0];
  Canvas.FillRect(Bounds, 0, 0, [], 1, aRowColor);
  Column.DefaultDrawCell(Canvas, Bounds, Row, Value, State);
```

Comment: See this cuestion:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32887019/font-color-on-a-stringgrid-with-firemonkey  or this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22095414/how-to-change-background-color-of-fmx-tgrid-row-depend-on-value-in-xe4

Answer (score 5):

Instead of calling `Column.DefaultDrawCell()`, you can use `FMX.Graphics.TCanvas.FillText()` in the grids `OnDrawColumnCell()` event.

The [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/FMX.Graphics.TCanvas.FillText) explains the details, but the main point is to set `Canvas.Fill.Color` to the desired color before calling `Canvas.FillText()`

Sample code:

```
procedure TForm28.Grid1DrawColumnCell(Sender: TObject; const Canvas: TCanvas;
  const Column: TColumn; const Bounds: TRectF; const Row: Integer;
  const Value: TValue; const State: TGridDrawStates);
begin
  case Row of
    0: Canvas.Fill.Color := TAlphaColors.Red;
    1: Canvas.Fill.Color := TAlphaColors.Blue;
    2: Canvas.Fill.Color := TAlphaColors.Green;
    3: Canvas.Fill.Color := TAlphaColors.Blueviolet;
  end;
  Canvas.FillText(Bounds, Value.AsString, false, 1, [], TTextAlign.Leading, TTextAlign.Center);
end;
```

And how it looks like:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  BTW, as of at least Delphi v10.2  TTextAlign.taLeading has been deprecated, use TTextAlign.Leading. The same goes for taCenter as now just Center and etc for others,